# Does "무료는 포함되지 않음" means “Ad-free not included”

Tags: translation

Currently, we're selling an in-app purchase item in a mobile app.

Even if the user has purchased the in-app purchase item, we will still show banner advertisement within the app.

To avoid the confusion, we are going to place this label, at the digital product item description.

```
Ad-free not included
```

If we were to translate it to Korean, is the following translation carry the exact meaning?

```
무료는 포함되지 않음
```

Thanks.

p/s We're a bit doubt on the above translation, we do not encounter wording "광고" (advertisement)

Comment: is this description going to be in the app or in the item being purchased? Once the item is purchased the ad will still be shown on the app. Is this what you mean? And what did you mean by "we do not encounter wording "광고" (advertisement)"? Are you saying you want to avoid the word 광고 in your phrasing?

Comment: Either way 무료 means free (as in, not costing money), so it wouldn't apply to what you are trying to say. Maybe 무광고 is the word you are looking for, but then your description would be for the app (as in the app will not be ad free)

Comment: That's a mistranslation. 무료 means no charge or cost.

Answer (score 3):

That sentence does not really make any sense.  It sounds like "free is not included".
Did you obtain that sentence from a computer translator?  This isn't a good idea when running a business - a good human translator will be much more reliable.  Computer translators sometimes get things right, and then you might think you can rely on them, but sometimes they get things very wrong - sometimes expressing the opposite of what you want.  This can be fatal for a business - you do not want to represent yourself falsely by accident.

If you do use a translator, fragment sentences like "ad-free not included" will likely give poor results; if you try to translate "Even if you make an in-app purchase, ads will still appear.", you'll get a much better translation (I tried [Papago](https://papago.naver.com/)):

> 인앱 구매를 해도 광고가 계속 나온다.

This is close to what I would have have written:

> 주의: 인앱구매를 하여도 광고 나옵니다.

But a professional translator or native Korean may be able to give a clear yet more concise translation that can be relied upon.

Comment: It is being translated by my user volunteer, who is a native Korean.

Answer (score 2):

`무료는 포함되지 않음` literally means:

> Free [version] doesn't include [it]

The sentence could make perfect sense if there was sufficient context for what `it` refers to, but that is not what you want.

What you want is:

> Ad-free [functionality] is not included

To keep it reasonably short and natural-sounding, I would loosely translate that as:

> 광고는 제거되지 않습니다